# Why SharePoint remote event receiver is referencing wrong url for our .SVC hosted inside azure web app

Tags: asp.net, azure, sharepoint, deployment, svc

I am working on building a remote event receiver for our SharePoint online root team site. and i am following the main approach mentioned in this link [remote-event-receivers-youre-all-doing-it-wrong](https://derekgusoff.wordpress.com/2017/11/08/remote-event-receivers-youre-all-doing-it-wrong/). where the approch worked well when i debug it using ngrok and running it from VS 2019. but when i deploy the RER inside azure web app, the RER stop working. Here are the details for the problem:-

1- Inside VS 2019 >> create a new asp.net web application >> add a .svc named rer.svc.

2- I generate the client and secret id, using this url `https://****.admin.sharepoint.com/_layouts/15/appregnew.aspx`
[image]

3- Then i access the app from the SP admin center @ `https://***-admin.sharepoint.com/_layouts/15/appinv.aspx` + i add this permission:-

```
 <AppPermissionRequests AllowAppOnlyPolicy="true">
 <AppPermissionRequest Scope="http://sharepoint/content/tenant" Right="FullControl" />
 </AppPermissionRequests>
```

[image]

4- I updated the asp.net web.config file with the client ID + secret ID generated from step-2.

5- I create a new App service inside azure with this url `https://tgrouppusrer.azurewebsites.net/rer.svc`.

6- After that i deploy the asp.net web application into azure using ftp :-

[image]

7- I access the service `https://tgrouppusrer.azurewebsites.net/rer.svc`, and i got this page:-
[image]

8- Finally i register 2 remote event receivers using this PnP script:-

```
Add-PnPEventReceiver -List "Project System" -Name "PUSRERupdating" -Url https://tgrouppusrer.azurewebsites.net/rer.svc -EventReceiverType ItemUpdating -Synchronization Synchronous

Add-PnPEventReceiver -List "Project System" -Name "PUSRERupdated" -Url https://tgrouppusrer.azurewebsites.net/rer.svc -EventReceiverType ItemUpdated -Synchronization Asynchronous
```

so on paper i should have everything working well. but when  update a list item inside our "Project System" list, the RER did not have any effect. so i open the azure application server logs and once i update a list item the logs will show this error:-

```
The default timeout is 2 hours. Change the timeout with the App Setting SCM_LOGSTREAM_TIMEOUT (in seconds).<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd"><html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"><head><title>IIS Detailed Error - 404.0 - Not Found</title><style type="text/css"><!--body{margin:0;font-size:.7em;font-family:Verdana,Arial,Helvetica,sans-serif;}code{margin:0;color:#006600;font-size:1.1em;font-weight:bold;}.config_source code{font-size:.8em;color:#000000;}pre{margin:0;font-size:1.4em;word-wrap:break-word;}ul,ol{margin:10px 0 10px 5px;}ul.first,ol.first{margin-}fieldset{padding:0 15px 10px 15px;word-break:break-all;}.summary-container fieldset{padding-bottom:5px;margin-}legend.no-expand-all{padding:2px 15px 4px 10px;margin:0 0 0 -12px;}legend{color:#333333;;margin:4px 0 8px -12px;_margin-font-weight:bold;font-size:1em;}a:link,a:visited{color:#007EFF;font-weight:bold;}a:hover{text-decoration:none;}h1{font-size:2.4em;margin:0;color:#FFF;}h2{font-size:1.7em;margin:0;color:#CC0000;}h3{font-size:1.4em;margin:10px 0 0 0;color:#CC0000;}h4{font-size:1.2em;margin:10px 0 5px 0;}#header{width:96%;margin:0 0 0 0;padding:6px 2% 6px 2%;font-family:"trebuchet MS",Verdana,sans-serif;color:#FFF;background-color:#5C87B2;}#content{margin:0 0 0 2%;;}.summary-container,.content-container{background:#FFF;width:96%;margin-padding:10px;;}.content-container p{margin:0 0 10px 0;}#details-left{width:35%;float:left;margin-right:2%;}#details-right{width:63%;float:left;}#server_version{width:96%;_height:1px;min-height:1px;margin:0 0 5px 0;padding:11px 2% 8px 2%;color:#FFFFFF;background-color:#5A7FA5;border-bottom:1px solid #C1CFDD;border-font-weight:normal;font-size:1em;color:#FFF;text-align:right;}#server_version p{margin:5px 0;}table{margin:4px 0 4px 0;width:100%;border:none;}td,th{vertical-align:top;padding:3px 0;text-align:left;font-weight:normal;border:none;}th{width:30%;text-align:right;padding-right:2%;font-weight:bold;}thead th{background-color:#ebebeb;width:25%;}#details-right th{width:20%;}table tr.alt td,table tr.alt th{}.highlight-code{color:#CC0000;font-weight:bold;font-style:italic;}.clear{clear:both;}.preferred{padding:0 5px 2px 5px;font-weight:normal;background:#006633;color:#FFF;font-size:.8em;}--></style>
</head><body><div id="content"><div class="content-container"><h3>HTTP Error 404.0 - Not Found</h3><h4>The resource you are looking for has been removed, had its name changed, or is temporarily unavailable.</h4></div><div class="content-container"><fieldset><h4>Most likely causes:</h4><ul>  <li>The directory or file specified does not exist on the Web server.</li>  <li>The URL contains a typographical error.</li>    <li>A custom filter or module, such as URLScan, restricts access to the file.</li> </ul></fieldset></div><div class="content-container"><fieldset><h4>Things you can try:</h4><ul>  <li>Create the content on the Web server.</li>  <li>Review the browser URL.</li>    <li>Create a tracing rule to track failed requests for this HTTP status code and see which module is calling SetStatus. For more information about creating a tracing rule for failed requests, click <a href="http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=66439">here</a>. </li> </ul></fieldset></div>
<div class="content-container"><fieldset><h4>Detailed Error Information:</h4><div id="details-left"><table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0"><tr class="alt"><th>Module</th><td>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;ManagedPipelineHandler</td></tr><tr><th>Notification</th><td>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;ExecuteRequestHandler</td></tr><tr class="alt"><th>Handler</th><td>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;svc-Integrated-4.0</td></tr><tr><th>Error Code</th><td>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;0x00000000</td></tr>
</table></div><div id="details-right"><table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0"><tr class="alt"><th>Requested URL</th><td>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;https://tGroupPUSRER:80/rer.svc</td></tr><tr><th>Physical Path</th><td>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;D:\home\site\wwwroot\rer.svc</td></tr><tr class="alt"><th>Logon Method</th><td>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;Anonymous</td></tr><tr><th>Logon User</th><td>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;Anonymous</td></tr>
</table><div class="clear"></div></div></fieldset></div>
<div class="content-container"><fieldset><h4>More Information:</h4>This error means that the file or directory does not exist on the server. Create the file or directory and try the request again.<p><a href="http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=62293&amp;IIS70Error=404,0,0x00000000,14393">View more information &raquo;</a></p><p>Microsoft Knowledge Base Articles:</p>

</fieldset></div></div></body></html>
2020-02-03 21:45:22 tGROUPPUSRER POST /rer.svc X-ARR-LOG-ID=666b6779-fca6-4a90-8e94-9c695780dae4 443 - 40.108.180.36 - - - tgrouppusrer.azurewebsites.net 404 0 0 372 8227 19
2020-02-03 21:45:22 tGROUPPUSRER POST /rer.svc X-ARR-LOG-ID=42637d01-4bdb-4345-843b-89713a935aa2 443 - 40.108.180.36 - - - tgrouppusrer.azurewebsites.net 404 0 0 372 8455 19
2020-02-03 21:45:33 tGROUPPUSRER POST /rer.svc X-ARR-LOG-ID=8696a37b-6881-4eb1-9110-701d4bddaeb5 443 - 40.108.180.145 - - - tgrouppusrer.azurewebsites.net 404 0 0 372 8187 46
2020-02-03 21:45:33 tGROUPPUSRER POST /rer.svc X-ARR-LOG-ID=8779cafe-fbc4-4094-9ff4-9fa10b884875 443 - 40.108.180.145 - - - tgrouppusrer.azurewebsites.net 404 0 0 372 8415 21
2020-02-03 21:45:43 ~1tGROUPPUSRER GET /api/commandstream/ping shell=CMD&_=1580765141131&X-ARR-LOG-ID=d4e5e91c-1062-44d4-9e94-e93cf6911357 443 - 165.225.80.94 Mozilla/5.0+(Windows+NT+10.0;+Win64;+x64)+AppleWebKit/537.36+(KHTML,+like+Gecko)+Chrome/79.0.3945.130+Safari/537.36 ARRAffinity=e8228ec522d0bb0cde1261622aaf3fb9855105fb7485023fe847aa1a3a4e8100 https://tgrouppusrer.scm.azurewebsites.net/DebugConsole tgrouppusrer.scm.azurewebsites.net 200 0 0 513 1582 0
2020-02-03 21:45:43 ~1tGROUPPUSRER GET /api/filesystemhub/ping _=1580765141130&X-ARR-LOG-ID=7e168704-35a9-4d2f-a4f9-b9e6f702a7ff 443 - 165.225.80.94 Mozilla/5.0+(Windows+NT+10.0;+Win64;+x64)+AppleWebKit/537.36+(KHTML,+like+Gecko)+Chrome/79.0.3945.130+Safari/537.36 ARRAffinity=e8228ec522d0bb0cde1261622aaf3fb9855105fb7485023fe847aa1a3a4e8100 https://tgrouppusrer.scm.azurewebsites.net/DebugConsole tgrouppusrer.scm.azurewebsites.net 200 0 0 513 1552 0<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd"><html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"><head><title>IIS Detailed Error - 404.0 - Not Found</title><style type="text/css"><!--body{margin:0;font-size:.7em;font-family:Verdana,Arial,Helvetica,sans-serif;}code{margin:0;color:#006600;font-size:1.1em;font-weight:bold;}.config_source code{font-size:.8em;color:#000000;}pre{margin:0;font-size:1.4em;word-wrap:break-word;}ul,ol{margin:10px 0 10px 5px;}ul.first,ol.first{margin-}fieldset{padding:0 15px 10px 15px;word-break:break-all;}.summary-container fieldset{padding-bottom:5px;margin-}legend.no-expand-all{padding:2px 15px 4px 10px;margin:0 0 0 -12px;}legend{color:#333333;;margin:4px 0 8px -12px;_margin-font-weight:bold;font-size:1em;}a:link,a:visited{color:#007EFF;font-weight:bold;}a:hover{text-decoration:none;}h1{font-size:2.4em;margin:0;color:#FFF;}h2{font-size:1.7em;margin:0;color:#CC0000;}h3{font-size:1.4em;margin:10px 0 0 0;color:#CC0000;}h4{font-size:1.2em;margin:10px 0 5px 0;}#header{width:96%;margin:0 0 0 0;padding:6px 2% 6px 2%;font-family:"trebuchet MS",Verdana,sans-serif;color:#FFF;background-color:#5C87B2;}#content{margin:0 0 0 2%;;}.summary-container,.content-container{background:#FFF;width:96%;margin-padding:10px;;}.content-container p{margin:0 0 10px 0;}#details-left{width:35%;float:left;margin-right:2%;}#details-right{width:63%;float:left;}#server_version{width:96%;_height:1px;min-height:1px;margin:0 0 5px 0;padding:11px 2% 8px 2%;color:#FFFFFF;background-color:#5A7FA5;border-bottom:1px solid #C1CFDD;border-font-weight:normal;font-size:1em;color:#FFF;text-align:right;}#server_version p{margin:5px 0;}table{margin:4px 0 4px 0;width:100%;border:none;}td,th{vertical-align:top;padding:3px 0;text-align:left;font-weight:normal;border:none;}th{width:30%;text-align:right;padding-right:2%;font-weight:bold;}thead th{background-color:#ebebeb;width:25%;}#details-right th{width:20%;}table tr.alt td,table tr.alt th{}.highlight-code{color:#CC0000;font-weight:bold;font-style:italic;}.clear{clear:both;}.preferred{padding:0 5px 2px 5px;font-weight:normal;background:#006633;color:#FFF;font-size:.8em;}--></style>
</head><body><div id="content"><div class="content-container"><h3>HTTP Error 404.0 - Not Found</h3><h4>The resource you are looking for has been removed, had its name changed, or is temporarily unavailable.</h4></div><div class="content-container"><fieldset><h4>Most likely causes:</h4><ul>  <li>The directory or file specified does not exist on the Web server.</li>  <li>The URL contains a typographical error.</li>    <li>A custom filter or module, such as URLScan, restricts access to the file.</li> </ul></fieldset></div><div class="content-container"><fieldset><h4>Things you can try:</h4><ul>  <li>Create the content on the Web server.</li>  <li>Review the browser URL.</li>    <li>Create a tracing rule to track failed requests for this HTTP status code and see which module is calling SetStatus. For more information about creating a tracing rule for failed requests, click <a href="http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=66439">here</a>. </li> </ul></fieldset></div>
<div class="content-container"><fieldset><h4>Detailed Error Information:</h4><div id="details-left"><table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0"><tr class="alt"><th>Module</th><td>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;ManagedPipelineHandler</td></tr><tr><th>Notification</th><td>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;ExecuteRequestHandler</td></tr><tr class="alt"><th>Handler</th><td>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;svc-Integrated-4.0</td></tr><tr><th>Error Code</th><td>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;0x00000000</td></tr>
</table></div><div id="details-right"><table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0"><tr class="alt"><th>Requested URL</th><td>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;https://tGroupPUSRER:80/rer.svc</td></tr><tr><th>Physical Path<
```

Generally speaking why it is trying to connect to "https://tgrouppusrer:80/rer.svc" while it should connect to "https://tgrouppusrer.azurewebsites.net/rer.svc" as specified in the PnP script to add the RER? could this be the problem?

Here is a screen shot of the above error when i save it a html:-
[image]

also inside Kudu i can see that the `rer.srv` is there, as follow:-

[image]

Also my original web.config is as follow:-

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<!--
  For more information on how to configure your ASP.NET application, please visit
  https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=169433
  -->
<configuration>
  <system.web>
    <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.5"/>
    <httpRuntime targetFramework="4.5"/>
  </system.web>
  <system.codedom>
    <compilers>
      <compiler language="c#;cs;csharp" extension=".cs"
        type="Microsoft.CodeDom.Providers.DotNetCompilerPlatform.CSharpCodeProvider, Microsoft.CodeDom.Providers.DotNetCompilerPlatform, Version=2.0.1.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35"
        warningLevel="4" compilerOptions="/langversion:6 /nowarn:1659;1699;1701"/>
      <compiler language="vb;vbs;visualbasic;vbscript" extension=".vb"
        type="Microsoft.CodeDom.Providers.DotNetCompilerPlatform.VBCodeProvider, Microsoft.CodeDom.Providers.DotNetCompilerPlatform, Version=2.0.1.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35"
        warningLevel="4" compilerOptions="/langversion:14 /nowarn:41008 /define:_MYTYPE=\&quot;Web\&quot; /optionInfer+"/>
    </compilers>
  </system.codedom>

  <system.serviceModel>
    <behaviors>
      <serviceBehaviors>
        <behavior name="">
          <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true" httpsGetEnabled="true" />
          <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="false" />
        </behavior>
      </serviceBehaviors>
    </behaviors>
    <serviceHostingEnvironment aspNetCompatibilityEnabled="true"
      multipleSiteBindingsEnabled="true" />
  </system.serviceModel>
  <appSettings file="custom.config">
    <add key="ClientId" value="****" />
    <add key="ClientSecret" value="****" />
  </appSettings>
  <system.web>
    <customErrors mode="Off"/>
  </system.web>
</configuration>
```

and based on this stack-overflow article [WCF hosted on SharePoint - Need to enable https](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17372612/wcf-hosted-on-sharepoint-need-to-enable-https), i modify my web.config as follow:-

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<!--
  For more information on how to configure your ASP.NET application, please visit
  https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=169433
  -->
<configuration>
  <system.web>
    <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.5"/>
    <httpRuntime targetFramework="4.5"/>
  </system.web>
  <system.codedom>
    <compilers>
      <compiler language="c#;cs;csharp" extension=".cs"
        type="Microsoft.CodeDom.Providers.DotNetCompilerPlatform.CSharpCodeProvider, Microsoft.CodeDom.Providers.DotNetCompilerPlatform, Version=2.0.1.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35"
        warningLevel="4" compilerOptions="/langversion:6 /nowarn:1659;1699;1701"/>
      <compiler language="vb;vbs;visualbasic;vbscript" extension=".vb"
        type="Microsoft.CodeDom.Providers.DotNetCompilerPlatform.VBCodeProvider, Microsoft.CodeDom.Providers.DotNetCompilerPlatform, Version=2.0.1.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35"
        warningLevel="4" compilerOptions="/langversion:14 /nowarn:41008 /define:_MYTYPE=\&quot;Web\&quot; /optionInfer+"/>
    </compilers>
  </system.codedom>

  <system.serviceModel>
    <services>
      <service name="TGroupPUSRER.RER">
        <endpoint
        address="/rer.svc"
        binding="webHttpBinding"
        contract="Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.EventReceivers.IRemoteEventService"
/>
      </service>
    </services>
    <bindings>
      <basicHttpBinding>
        <binding name="secureBinding">
          <security mode="Transport" />
        </binding>
      </basicHttpBinding>
    </bindings>
    <protocolMapping>
      <remove scheme="http"/>
      <add binding="basicHttpBinding" scheme="https" bindingConfiguration="secureBinding" />
    </protocolMapping>
    <behaviors>
      <serviceBehaviors>
        <behavior name="">
          <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true" httpsGetEnabled="true" />
          <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="false" />
        </behavior>
      </serviceBehaviors>
      <endpointBehaviors>
        <behavior >
          <webHttp/>
        </behavior>
      </endpointBehaviors>
    </behaviors>
    <serviceHostingEnvironment aspNetCompatibilityEnabled="true" multipleSiteBindingsEnabled="true" />
  </system.serviceModel>
  <appSettings file="custom.config">
    <add key="ClientId" value="***" />
    <add key="ClientSecret" value="***" />
  </appSettings>
</configuration>
```

but i still get the file not found error inside azure logs.

Comment: can you share what you put on `appregnew.aspx`? especially `App Domain` and `Redirect URI` on that page?

Comment: @ChunLiu thanks for the reply. i updated the question with 2 screen shots on point 2 and point 2 which show the `appregnew.aspx` ..

Comment: @ChunLiu is the info i provided sound valid to you?

Comment: It's hard to see what is wrong without debugging. Maybe you can try to follow some other online tutorials from scratch, like [this one](https://www.sptechcon.com/blog/steps-to-create-a-remote-event-receiver-using-visual-studio-2015-for-sharepoint-online-and-deploy-into-microsoft-azure) or [this one](https://www.tatvasoft.com.au/blog/how-to-implement-remote-event-receiver-in-sharepoint-online/).

Comment: Did you follow the directions provided in step 7?

Comment: @kpie can you explain your point in more details?

Comment: Did you test with svcutil.exe?

Comment: @kpie no i did not test it. actually i did not use `svcutil.exe` before

Answer (score 1):

In step #6 you show the Destination URL starting with 'http'

Instead, it should start with 'https' to reflect the other settings you are using.

Honestly, I can't even really consider this an answer, but it might be that simple.

Also, in step #3 you have a trailing slash in your Redirect URL, yet the example does not include a trailing slash, so I'd remove that as well.

Comment: inside the azure web app i get the "Get publish profile", and inside this profile i copy/paste the ftp settings. where inside the Destination URL specify it with http and not with https...